# What insect could be eating the tops of baby zinnia plants?

Tags: seedlings, insects, zinnia

My zinnia seedlings emerge outside in my garden, but right away the leaves are eaten to the stem on some of them.This didn’t happened last year.

Answer (score 4):

I would not reach for "insect" first here. I'd put my first guess on gastropods (slugs and/or snails.)

You can try various things, such as a ring of copper wire around the plants.

You can also try going out at night with a flashlight to catch them in the act if they are not as bold as the ones around here (more are out at night, but plenty will eat things in daylight, too.)

Answer (score 1):

We also get sparrows eating leaves of new seedlings.  Many people cut the bottom off a 2 liter soda bottle and use it to protect the plants.  Others use fabric row covers.  A plastic ring from a pint or quart container with the bottom cut out seems to work well also.